# Enable audit command for enterprise registry npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

My question is about how to enable npm audit command in my npm enterprise
registry

When I am trying to run npm audit command i am getting the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ENOAUDIT",
    "summary": "Your configured registry (https://registry.npmjs.mydomain/) does not support audit requests.",
    "detail": ""
  }
}
```

Here is my research

I tried with the following command and its working

```
npm audit --json --registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

But when I use

```
npm audit --json --registry https://registry.npmjs.mydomain/
```

It does not work.
How can I configure to make my registry to work with npm audit command

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have the same problem. We're using artifactory for private npm registry which [doesn't support npm audit yet](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-16670). Simplest solution which works for me is:

`npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org`

**Alternative solution**:

1. backup config file for your private registry (most probably it's ~/.npmrc)
2. change registry on public npm: `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org`
3. use `npm audit` / `npm audit fix`
4. revert private registry configuration back

**Update 2020**

In case of [artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) private npm registry - It does support npm audit now, so you can use `npm audit` / `npm audit fix` there without any additional configuration. But if your private npm registry still doesn't support npm audit – steps above will be valid for you.

Comment: Does this mean there's no way of auditing a private registry up until now?

Comment: @christopherdejesus, `npm audit` is a tool provided by npm and in order to use it - you need to have package you want to audit in npm's registry. But, if you have packages in your private registry which you don't want to publish to npm - use paid/another audit tool ;) For example this tool https://snyk.io has integration with jFrog solutions

Answer (score 1):

Jfrog Artifactory now fully support the 'npm audit' command (since version 6.10)

Furthermore, Using Jfrog Xray in combination with Artifactory will also enrich the audit report with more vulnerabilities and security info From Xray database.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory6.10

Comment: Can `npm audit` and `npm audit fix` be used with out Xray (Xray requires Pro X subscription) ?

Comment: Yes. Artifactory supports npm audit (and audit fix) without Xray as this command is officially part of npm commands. However, using npm audit with Xray will be enhanced with a set of results which will contain more CVEs and vulnerabilities originating from Xray's continuously growing vulnerabilities database

Comment: Thank you @yoaz for the info